# Error ORA-12507 al conectar desde una aplicación Java

Tags: java, oracle-21c

Estoy tratando de conectar una java con base de datos oracle 21c express edition y me sale el siguiente error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor
The Connection descriptor used by the client was:
127.0.0.1:1521:XE
```

Answer (score 0):

En Oracle, hace rato ya que es mala idea usar la aproximación de SID como identificador. Puede considerarse *legacy* y no recomendado.

Para buscar la instancia por serviceName, cambia la cadena de conexión a

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE`

Nótese el cambio de `:XE` a `/XE`